# How Saved is my game?

Tags: outer-wilds

I know I'm late to the party, but I've been trying to play through avoiding spoilers, and I've reached a point where I'm afraid I might wipe my progress. The research on saving I've been able to do while avoiding triggers seems to tell me under what conditions the game starts to save, but not how thorough that save is.

> Specifically, all of my ideas on what to do next involve removing the Warp Core from the Ash Twin project, which seems lore-wise as though this should end my game, one way or another.

However, if this is the situation, I don't see a method of copying save files that I would expect to exist.

> Does this mean that after breaking the source of the loop, I can continue loading saves as before? Maintaining the knowledge and ship's logs I've gathered?

If not, is there an external way of backing up these saves/copying them to another slot so I can potentially explore multiple scenarios?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to worry about progress being wiped. You'll be able to reload your save [even after beating Outer Wilds](https://reddit.com/r/outerwilds/comments/gwv4pc/can_i_complete_the_ship_log_after_finishing_the/).

> Regardless of what happens after you remove the Warp Core, you will be able to load your save by selecting "Resume your expedition" on the main menu.

More specifically:

> If you die after the Warp Core is removed, you will get a game over screen before being returned to the main menu.